# bash loop to assign variables values without overwriting previously declared variables

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, global-variables, associative-array

The setup we currently have is to declare several variables in a config file and then we run some processes that depend on those variables. Additional functionality that I'm trying to provide is a default_variables script that will give default values to all the variables in the config files, while not overriding anything that is declared in the config file.

Here is my current code:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# allows var to be used as an associative array
declare -A var

# variable declarations must be of the form:
# var[var_name]=var_value
# after processing loop, the above will be evaluated as:
# export var_name=var_value

# declare default variables
var[a]=a_val
var[b]=b_val
var[c]=c_val
var[d]=d_val

# iterate on associative array indices
for default_var in `echo "${!var[@]}"`
do

test_var=\$${default_var}

  # only export variables that have not been previously declared
  if [[ -z `eval $test_var` ]]
  then

    # export each index name as a variable
    export $default_var=${var[$default_var]}
  fi
done
```

The error I'm currently getting is that the eval statement tries to execute the value of a variable if it was declared before the script was ran. For instance, if the above script were ran twice then the error would be:

```
-sh: a_val: command not found
-sh: b_val: command not found
-sh: c_val: command not found
-sh: d_val: command not found
```

Now I am definitely up for a more elegant way of solving this problem, but this is the best I could come up with. Finally, I know that exporting the values normally and checking each variable individually to see if they are allocated would be a more "correct" way of doing this, but I don't want to exponentially bloat the script and I don't want people to have to copy the logic every time they want to add a new variable to the script and I can't just run the default_variables script before the config file allowing it to override the default values because some default values depend on config values.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `eval`, which causes its argument to be executed as a command. All you want is the value of the variable named by `$default_var`. There is a perfectly good syntax for indirect variable reference:

```
if [[ -z ${!default_var} ]]
```

Although you really wanted to test for non-empty. `-z` tests for empty. So it should be.

```
if [[ -n ${!default_var} ]]
```

Also, this is overcomplicated, and arguably incorrect:

```
for default_var in `echo "${!var[@]}"`
```

Just write:

```
for default_var in "${!var[@]}"
```

Comment: Right on all counts sir! Except for the -n option, I'm wanted to test for empty, because if it's empty then I want to assign a value, otherwise skip over it, but ${!default_var} did the job and the echo command was indeed not needed. I was trying to be over cautious on my first draft of the script since I was nesting variables :)

Comment: Ah I see now that the comment that I put was actually misleading as to my intentions as far as the -n/-z was concerned. I reworded it to say "only export variables that have not been previously declared"

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

# allows var to be used as an associative array
declare -A var

# variable declarations must be of the form:
# var[var_name]=var_value
# after processing loop, the above will be evaluated as:
# export var_name=var_value

# declare default variables
var[a]=a_val
var[b]=b_val
var[c]=c_val
var[d]=d_val

# iterate on associative array indices
for default_var in "${!var[@]}"; do     #<=== no ugly `echo ...` needed
    [[ "${!default_var}" ]] && continue #<=== indirect expansion
    # export each index name as a variable
    export "$default_var=${var[$default_var]}" #<=== use quotes!
done

echo "a=$a"
echo "b=$b"
echo "c=$c"
echo "d=$d"
```

I called this script `banana`:

```
$ ./banana
a=a_val
b=b_val
c=c_val
d=d_val
$ a=gorilla ./banana
a=gorilla
b=b_val
c=c_val
d=d_val
```

Now this only checks if the variable is unset or empty, that is a user can't explicitly make a variable empty:

```
$ a= ./banana
a=a_val
b=b_val
c=c_val
d=d_val
```

To support this, you can instead do:

```
for default_var in "${!var[@]}"; do     #<=== no ugly `echo ...` needed
    if ! declare -p "$default_var" &>/dev/null; then
    # export each index name as a variable
        export "$default_var=${var[$default_var]}" #<=== use quotes!
    fi
done
```

so that:

```
$ a= ./banana
a=
b=b_val
c=c_val
d=d_val
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
# iterate on associative array indices (no need to do `echo ...`)
for default_var in "${!var[@]}"
do
    # skip variables that have been previously declared (even if their value is null)
    if [[ -z ${!default_var+.} ]]
    then
        # export each index name as a variable (the safer way with quotes)
        export "$default_var=${var[$default_var]}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: `[[ ! -v $default_var ]]`. fwiw.

Comment: @rici True but only starting bash 4.2

Comment: Yup. Only a third of a decade old. Of course, there are still those who consider C99 too new-fangled to use. :)

Comment: @rici I hope you don't joke to assume that all users upgrade their systems easily.

Comment: Not at all. I myself still use a teletype to communicate with a mainframe, as I have done since I started in this field. Although my fingers are getting weary, it just doesn't feel right without the clatter.